# Rearranging formulas with fractions

Tags: linear-algebra

For the following question:

Make $R_1$ the subject of the equation

$\frac{1}{R} = \frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2} + \frac{1}{R_3}$

Is there a quicker way than multiplying each $R$ term individually, before factorising? Which I think gets me the following answer:

$R_1=\frac{RR_2R_3}{R_2R_3-RR_3-RR_2}$

For example, isn't the following a correct rearrangement of the original question:

$R^{-1} = R_1^{-1} + R_2^{-1} + R_3^{-1}$

And if so, why do I end up with a different result?

Comment: Writing $\frac{1}{R} = \frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2} + \frac{1}{R_3}$ as $R^{-1} = R_1^{-1} + R_2^{-1} + R_3^{-1}$ is like writing $(x+y)^2$ as $x^2+y^2$, which is wrong.

Comment: @MCCCS No, it’s exactly the same equation with slightly different notation.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{R_1}=\frac{1}{R}-\frac{1}{R_2}-\frac{1}{R_3}=\frac{R_2R_3-RR_2-RR_3}{RR_2R_3},$$
which gives
$$R_1=\frac{RR_2R_3}{R_2R_3-RR_2-RR_3}$$

Answer (score 1):

> For example, isn't the following a correct rearrangement of the original question:
>
> $R^{-1} = R_1^{-1} + R_2^{-1} + R_3^{-1}$

Sure, this is the correct rewriting of the original equation. From this, you can get

$$R_1^{-1} = R^{-1} - R_2^{-1}-R_3^{-1}$$
which you can then rewrite as

$$R_1=\left(R^{-1} - R_2^{-1}-R_3^{-1}\right)^{-1}$$